# Running jsp files from /srv/http using Apache HTTP server and Tomcat

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat

I'd like run jsp files directly from `/srv/http` without deploying them the Tomcat-way. For example, I want to be able to create symbolic link to my webapp directory (e.g. /home/user/myapp/) in /srv/http and access some app's page through `http://localhost/myapp/page.jsp`.

Is this possible and how would I set this up?

NOTE: This is not for production. We have to use JSP at university and I want to be able to quickly test my pages.

Answer (score 1):

Open the `server.xml` of your `Tomcat`. Assuming if your are using Tomcat 6.x+ then it would be at `/tomcatDir/conf/server.xml`.

Make an entry with your path

```
<Context path="/myapp" docBase="yourPathGoesHere" debug="0" reloadable="true" />
```

Restart Tomcat if already running.

Comment: Isn't this the classic "tomcat way"? Thanks anyway, I'm glad it's this easy, if I ever wanted to do it this way.

Comment: Yes It is.. BTW When I answered the question title was different.Hope It would be useful

Answer (score 0):

What I did at the moment was creating a symlink in `/var/lib/tomcatX/webapps` to my project path. This is not the answer I was looking for though, but it is a way to deploy an app without much work.

(`X` in the above path means your Tomcat version)

Answer (score 0):

If you set `<Host name="localhost" appBase="/srv/http">` then all of the directories in it will be deployed as web applications.

If you want `/srv/http` to be the ROOT application/directory add a file: `tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml`

with the Context `docBase="/srv/http"`, rather than adding a Context definition to server.xml - this has been strongly discouraged for years.